# Typescript generic interface with field that references the generic class (not instance) type

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, generics, instance

Let's say I have a typescript class `A`, and a class `B` that `extends A`

```
class A {
  static a(): number { return 10; }
  a_(): number { return 10; }
}

class B extends A {
  static b(): number { return 20; }
  b_(): number { return 20; }
}
```

I would like to define a generic typescript interface, like so:

```
interface ClassAndInstance<C extends A> {
  c: ClassType<C>
  i: C
}
```

(Note: `ClassType` here refers to the class (not instance) of the generic type.)

Now, if I have an instance of the `ClassAndInstance`

```
ci: ClassAndInstance<B>;
```

I want to be able to call both the class and the instance fields of B, like so:

```
ci.c.a();  // 10
ci.c.b();  // 20
ci.i.a_(); // 10
ci.i.b_(); // 20;
```

How would I define `ClassType` to achieve this in a type safe manner?

I've chosen an interface to define the semantics behind `ClassAndInstance`, but if there's any other way of achieving this, that would work too.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMROZW) work for you?  The instance type `B` doesn't know anything about its constructor type `typeof B`, but the constructor type does know about the type it constructs.  So you will need to do `ClassAndInstance<typeof B>` and not `ClassAndInstance<B>`, if that's okay.  Let me know if you want to see this written up as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz oh that’s smart, instead of passing in the instance type, and trying to infer the class type from it, you directly pass in the class type. How clever! ;)

Comment: This definitely works for me, feel free to post this as an answer and I’ll happily accept it :) thanks!!